# Security hash key based on combination of values

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have large sets of records/documents in MongoDB and i need to limit access to items by a combination of values that i have in a list in each document.

Imagine the possible, single values for the security are [1, 2, 3].

A record could have any combination of those, which would be: 
() (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)

- A user who has access to [1], would only be able to see the records that have () & (1)
- A user who has access to [2], would only be able to see the records that have () & (2)
- A user who has access to [1, 2], would only be able to see the records that have (), (1), (2), (1, 2)
- Only a user who can access [1, 2, 3] would be able to see all records

Now at the entry point into the database I know what the access of the user is, for instance [1, 2, 3]. But I cannot easily (esp. indexed) look through the records to retrieve all the values the user has access to.

Creating a function to make unique hashes for each record, would be quite easy:

```
def hash_combination(input):
    return hash(frozenset(input))
```

This would give me a unique key for each record, which we can index use as filters. And then getting all possible keys for a user is easy too:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s) + 1))

def hash_powerset(iterable):
    return [hash(frozenset(x)) for x in powerset(iterable)]
```

But the actual list of possible unique inputs for the combinations can be quite large (50+), creating a factor that is way too large to be practical.

I can think only of two possible solutions. Number one is a row-by-row check:

```
security_list = (1, 2, 3)
for row in db.collection.find():
    # check security
    if any(x not in security_list for x in row['row_security']):
        continue
    # security passed
    pass
```

But that's quite a performance killer. The other one is to invert the selection to a "what we cannot see":

```
unique_list = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
security_list = (1, 2, 3)
not_allowed_list = (x for x in unique_list if x not in security_list)
for row in db.collection.find({'row_security': {'$nin': not_allowed_list}}):
    # security passed
    pass
```

But this also is an operation that mongodb cannot index (likely because of similar reasons as what I'm encountering now), so still not good for performance. Better than the previous option (as you avoid the conversion to python objects as a bottleneck), but still not great

Some specifics for our case:

- we always know the security list of the user
- we always know the unique list of values possible (and this can be large)
- python 2.7, mongodb 3.0

Are there other methods? What would be the best way to approach this?

Kind regards,

Carst

Comment: This looks like a good question for *Code Review* (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: To be honest, I find it difficult at times to choose which one is the best. But I based it on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in which points to stackoverflow for "a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm"

Comment: I guess [__acl__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acl+mongodb) is the proper name for the system you are inventing.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with Python Zen, you *first* invent a clean solution and *only then* go about optimizing it *if you actually see that it needs optimization*.

So, as you can see, there are actually *two* tasks here: 1) work out a general algorithm, 2) optimize the algorithm for the specific environment.

---

At the core of your task is:

- Given:

  - each record has a set of flags (1,2,3) marking "privileges/clearance levels" required to access it
  - a user too has a set of the same flags, specifying their clearance levels
- Problem:

  - return all the records the user has access to

Now that it's formulated like this, the answer is trivial:

```
result = {record for record in set_ if user.mask >= record.mask}
```

---

Now, for the 2nd task, you need to check which operations MongoDB does efficiently and figure out how to implement this operation using them.

Comment: Hi, completely agree with the Python Zen and I must emphasize that the two solutions I gave both work functionally. The first solution is basically a real life mongodb version of your suggestion. I must say that the title of my question maybe could have been better.
The thing is: the type of algorithm and inclusion/exclusion method of the mask matter incredibly much here, which is why i'm diving into the performance part after each solution. This stops both theoretically functional solutions from being pragmatically feasible :/